# Anybody know how to add an arrow style to a EE LineString?

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to add an arrow style to a LineString in Earth Engine, pointing in the direction that the LineString coordinates were created.

The only style options I see are solid, dotted, dashed.  Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm currently looking for a solution.

Comment: Nope, never did

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I find anything I'll report back here. Take care